# Java JButton to delete everything on JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

I am having trouble figuring out how to delete everything on a JPanel or even the JPanel itself from a JFrame from the click of a button. I tried the removeAll,revalidate and repaint methods but all of them gave me a non-static clause problem. I want by pressing the "back" button to delete the JPanel and go directly to the JFrame. Is that possible in this scenario? This is what I've got so far:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;;
public void setRandomNum() {
    randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
}

int cWins = 0;

String AIGuess;
String myGuess;

JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
JButton back = new JButton("Back");

JLabel AIGuessDisplay = new JLabel("<html>Computer Played: " + "<br>You Played: " + "</br></html>");
JLabel cWinsLabel = new JLabel("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");

public Panel() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(rock);
    rock.addActionListener(
              new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        myGuess = "Rock";
                        if (randomNum == 1) {
                            AIGuess = "Rock";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                        }
                        if (randomNum == 2) {
                            AIGuess = "Paper";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                            cWins = 0;
                        }
                        if (randomNum == 3) {
                            AIGuess = "Scissors";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                            cWins++;
                        }
                        setRandomNum();
                        AIGuessDisplay.setText("<html>Computer Played: " + AIGuess + "<br>You Played: " + myGuess + "</br></html>");
                        cWinsLabel.setText("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
                    }
                  }
                );
    add(paper);
    paper.addActionListener(
              new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        myGuess = "Paper";
                        if (randomNum == 1) {
                            AIGuess = "Rock";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                            cWins++;
                        }
                        if (randomNum == 2) {
                            AIGuess = "Paper";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                        }
                        if (randomNum == 3) {
                            AIGuess = "Scissors";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                            cWins = 0;
                        }
                        setRandomNum();
                        AIGuessDisplay.setText("<html>Computer Played: " + AIGuess + "<br>You Played: " + myGuess + "</br></html>");
                        cWinsLabel.setText("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
                    }
                  }
                );

    add(scissors);
    scissors.addActionListener(
              new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        myGuess = "Scissors";
                        if (randomNum == 1) {
                            AIGuess = "Rock";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                            cWins = 0;
                        }
                        if (randomNum == 2) {
                            AIGuess = "Paper";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                            cWins++;
                        }
                        if (randomNum == 3) {
                            AIGuess = "Scissors";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                        }
                        setRandomNum();
                        AIGuessDisplay.setText("<html>Computer Played: " + AIGuess + "<br>You Played: " + myGuess + "</br></html>");
                        cWinsLabel.setText("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
                    }
                  }
                );
    add(AIGuessDisplay);
    add(back);
    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }           
    });
    add(cWinsLabel);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

This is my main class:

```
public class Application extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton rps = new JButton("Rock Paper Scissors");

public Application() {

    getContentPane().setLayout(
            new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    add(rps);
    rps.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            add(new Panel());
            rps.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    setSize(500,150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Mini Games");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Application ex = new Application();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeAll()`, `revalidate()`, and `repaint()` is the standard way to remove components from a jpanel. Like so:

```
...
back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Panel.this.removeAll();
        Panel.this.revalidate();
        Panel.this.repaint();
    }           
});
...
```

If this is what you tried and you are still receiving a problem, perhaps you could show the snippet your IDE wants to declare as static.

Comment: Excuse me for being a rookie but why are we using "this" after Panel?

Comment: `this` is a special keyword that can be used in non static methods to get the current instance of the running class. `Panel` is a class, and not an instance, however if we use `this` in a method in `Panel`, we will get the correct instance to do with what we please.  Also, we must say `Panel.this`, instead of just `this` because `new ActionListener` denotes that you've entered an anonymous inner class, and any calls to `this` will result in the instance of the `ActionListener` instead of our instance of `Panel` that we wanted.

Comment: Also do note that if there is no "class  namespace", ie `removeAll()` without `Panel.this`, then `this` is implied! So if we tried calling `removeAll()` without `Panel.this` our IDE will complain that it cannot find the method `removeAll()` in the instance of `ActionListener` implied by `this`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. One way is to have a method in the Application class that manipulates the contents of it class. Then pass the Application object to the child object so that the child can call the Application's method. The code below has a reload() method in the Application class and that method is called inside the Panel class.

```
public class Application extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton rps = new JButton("Rock Paper Scissors");

    Panel p;
    public Application() {

        getContentPane().setLayout(
                new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        add(rps);
        rps.addActionListener(this);
        setSize(500,150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Mini Games");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            //       @Override
            public void run() {
                Application ex = new Application();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public void reload() {
        p.setVisible(false);
        this.remove(p);
        this.rps.setVisible(true);
    }

    //@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        p = new Panel(this);
        add(p);
        rps.setVisible(false);
    }



    public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;;
        public void setRandomNum() {
            randomNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
        }

        int cWins = 0;

        String AIGuess;
        String myGuess;

        JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
        JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
        JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
        JButton back = new JButton("Back");

        JLabel AIGuessDisplay = new JLabel("<html>Computer Played: " + "<br>You Played: " + "</br></html>");
        JLabel cWinsLabel = new JLabel("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
        Application app = null;

        public Panel(Application caller) {
            app = caller;
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            add(rock);
            rock.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    myGuess = "Rock";
                    if (randomNum == 1) {
                        AIGuess = "Rock";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                    }
                    if (randomNum == 2) {
                        AIGuess = "Paper";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                        cWins = 0;
                    }
                    if (randomNum == 3) {
                        AIGuess = "Scissors";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                        cWins++;
                    }
                    setRandomNum();
                    AIGuessDisplay.setText("<html>Computer Played: " + AIGuess + "<br>You Played: " + myGuess + "</br></html>");
                    cWinsLabel.setText("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
                }
            }
            );
            add(paper);
            paper.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    myGuess = "Paper";
                    if (randomNum == 1) {
                        AIGuess = "Rock";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                        cWins++;
                    }
                    if (randomNum == 2) {
                        AIGuess = "Paper";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                    }
                    if (randomNum == 3) {
                        AIGuess = "Scissors";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                        cWins = 0;
                    }
                    setRandomNum();
                    AIGuessDisplay.setText("<html>Computer Played: " + AIGuess + "<br>You Played: " + myGuess + "</br></html>");
                    cWinsLabel.setText("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
                }
            }
            );

            add(scissors);
            scissors.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    myGuess = "Scissors";
                    if (randomNum == 1) {
                        AIGuess = "Rock";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
                        cWins = 0;
                    }
                    if (randomNum == 2) {
                        AIGuess = "Paper";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win");
                        cWins++;
                    }
                    if (randomNum == 3) {
                        AIGuess = "Scissors";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie");
                    }
                    setRandomNum();
                    AIGuessDisplay.setText("<html>Computer Played: " + AIGuess + "<br>You Played: " + myGuess + "</br></html>");
                    cWinsLabel.setText("<html><br><br>" + "Consecutive Wins: " + cWins + "</br></br></html>");
                }
            }
            );
            add(AIGuessDisplay);
            add(back);
            back.addActionListener(this);
            add(cWinsLabel);
        }

        // @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            app.reload();
        }
    }
}
```